# What objective winning criteria should be specified for a popularity + code trolling contest?

Tags: discussion

For a question that is a code trolling, popularity contest, what types of "objective" criteria should be listed in order to prevent the question from being closed?

Is "this is a code trolling contest; user with the most votes by X date is the winner" enough?

Answer (score 4):

The tag wiki for [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) is contradictory:

> Unless specified otherwise, the highest-voted answer wins.

Further down:

> In this site, every question must have a clear winning criteria. It is not enough to state that in the problem description, you must add the specific tag too. For code-trolling the winning criteria would normally be [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), but this winning criteria **will not be implied**, so you must manually add it, be it popularity-contest or something else.

I feel the second is a better idea, for clarity's sake, so I've submitted a suggested edit to it to remove the first.

If you have both tags, then it's a popularity contest, but it won't hurt to explicitly state "most votes" in the body.